# Why whenever I type something that does not exist, i got this error?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

Whenever I type something that does not exist in the json I got this error:

```
TypeError: countries.map is not a function
```

The search functionality works fine until I type in a result that doesn't exist.

```
const mainUrl = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/`
const all = `${'all'}`
const serachUrl = `${'name/'}`

const Home = () => {
  // usesstate to conutries
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  // usesstate to query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

  {
    /* // fetch countries */
  }
  const fetchCountries = async () => {
    let url
    if (query) {
      url = `${mainUrl}${serachUrl}${query}`
    } else {
      url = `${mainUrl}${all}`
    }
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const data = await response.json()
      setCountries(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCountries()
  }, [query])
```

Comment: My guess is that your server returns null (or some other non-array), you set countries to null in your component's state, and then attempt to invoke `map` on it.

Comment: Please provide your return statement where you call countries.map

Comment: I dont know how to format code in comments here.

Comment: `<Grid>
        {countries.map((country) => {
          console.log(country)
          return <Countries key={country.name} {...country} />
        })}
      </Grid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

When you search for something that doesn't exist the API is returning an error object, a 404.

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
}
```

This is stored in `countries` state and you then attempt to map it, OFC throwing the error.

## Solution

[Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

> A `fetch()` promise will reject with a `TypeError` when a network error is
> encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this
> usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute
> a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful
> `fetch()` would include checking that the promise resolved, then
> checking that the `Response.ok` property has a value of true.

The `fetch` API returns a resolved Promise even for 400 responses. You should check that the request was successful.

```
const fetchCountries = async () => {
  let url;
  if (query) {
    url = `${mainUrl}${serachUrl}${query}`;
  } else {
    url = `${mainUrl}${all}`;
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) { // <-- check OK response
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    setCountries(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

[image: Edit why-whenever-i-type-something-that-does-not-exist-i-got-this-error]

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something I didn't know :)